# How context switch happen in kernel to user while creating fd?

Tags: linux-kernel

How context switch happen in kernel to user while creating fd? because user to kernel contextAswitch happen it will trigg a INT ox80 signanl.but in kernel to user how it happen?

Answer (score 0):

You should read something about operating systems, like [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) (freely downloadable). You could also read books about the implementation of the Linux kernel. Don't forget to study the source code of the Linux [kernel](http://kernel.org/) and to look on [`kernelnewbies`](http://kernelnewbies.org/).

The usual way a kernel creates a [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) for a user-mode application is thru a [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) such as [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html).

During the processing of that system call, the [scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)#Process_scheduler) could be invoked and make a [context switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch).

For `open` the kernel needs to do some [path_resolution(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html), and that processing may require disk access (for file metadata not already sitting in the [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache)) so is likely to require some context switch. As soon as the kernel needs some disk access, it will do a context switch (to let some other runnable process to run). After the disk controller (or [DMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_memory_access) controller) signals the end of the disk block transfer thru some [interrupt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt), the kernel might reschedule the process.

Remember that a disk access can [take](http://norvig.com/21-days.html#answers) dozen of milliseconds; during that time several context switches could happen, and the processor has time to execute millions of machine code instructions.

Read also about [continuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation) and [continuation-passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style). These concepts do apply to the kernel and its process scheduler.

Also experiment with `/proc` (see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)) on your Linux computer. For example, repeat the `cat /proc/interrupts` command twice in a second or two, and observe the differences. You'll understand that context switches happen often (perhaps a thousand switches per second) on your computer.

See also the [OSDEV wiki](http://osdev.org/).

BTW, recent linux systems don't use the `INT 0x80` machine instruction to switch to kernel mode (but some `SYSENTER` or `SYSCALL` machine instruction). See also [vdso(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vdso.7.html).